# What is the best way to ensure all AngularJS directives have loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to let a controller know once all directives have loaded? I am having a problem calling a function from an object shared between a directive, a factory and a controller.

The function to be called is defined in the directive. The function runs if it is called from the controller within a `$timeout` with a one second delay, however, a `vm.item.test is not a function` error is thrown if called without `$timeout`.  Is there an event that AngularJS broadcasts once it is loaded?

What is the best way to ensure all directives have loaded?

I've created a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7dv7LwZQnT4UpSJ3R4nV?p=preview) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Probably using a promise? http://plnkr.co/edit/vP5ylp?p=preview Or use eventing to notify the specific component has rendered. http://plnkr.co/edit/F6Xj3f?p=preview

Comment: If you're using `ui-router`, try using `resolve`.

Comment: @shmck, I am using `resolve` which stops the controller from loading  until promises are resolved, but directives don't load until after the controller loads, so `resolve` is not relevant.

Comment: @PSL, I'm leading towards broadcasting an event.  Thank you for answer.